# Java Stream Reduce Method

Tags: java, list, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

What is the reduce method actually doing here? I've read the Oracle docs but I still don't understand what the reduce method is doing here in this example

```
public static Coder findCoderWithWorstBMI(List<Coder> coders) {
    return coders.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(BMICalculator::calculateBMI))
            .reduce((first, second) -> second).orElse(null);
}

private static double calculateBMI(Coder coder) {
    double height = coder.getHeight();
    double weight = coder.getWeight();
    if (height == 0.0)
        throw new ArithmeticException();
    double bmi = weight / (height * height);
    return Math.round(bmi * 100) / 100.0;
}
```

Comment: Just as you may know, you can `reverse` a `Comparator` as well and then `findFirst` of such an element. Which then forms a combination of `sort`+`findFirst` easily replaceable with `min` or `max` APIs.

Comment: @Naman still it's better not to sort the entire collection

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)):

> Optional reduce​(BinaryOperator accumulator)
>
> Performs a reduction on the elements of this stream, using an associative accumulation function, and returns an Optional describing the reduced value, if any.

This means `reduce` takes a `BinaryOperator<T>` - a specific function that takes two parameters of type `T` and produces one with the same type.

You stream might have any number of `Coder` instances, the reducing function takes two `Coder`s and returns the second one. This means, that from the whole stream the last `Coder` wrapped in `Optional` is returned if there are any and empty `Optional` if the stream was empty in the first place.

Note, that this can be written more efficiently:

```
coders.stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(BMICalculator::calculateBMI))
    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: @user85421 efficient in terms of performance and readability, that's what I had in mind :)

Comment: the only case with such stream to return the value of `orElse` is when the underlying collection is empty, showing the absence of items and that corresponds logically better to `Optional<Coder>` rather than `coder==null` to be returned from the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
.reduce((first, second) -> second).orElse(null);
```

the reduce method will execute if first and second values are present other orElse(null) which takes a null will return null.